# Conditional Count Across Selected Columns in Python

Tags: python

I'm new to Python and want to make a new column in a data frame that counts all active values across all columns:

```
ID  2000  2001  2002  2003  ...  2019  new_column
1  active  active  nan  active  ...  nan  3
2  active  nan  nan  active  ...  nan  2
```

Since i have quite a lot of columns so i don't want to specify each column name. Is there a quick way to calculate this number?

Thank you very much!

Comment: When you say active you mean all non-nan values?

Comment: yes, i can start with non-nan, but still prefer something specifically as comparing value = 'active' since i also have other columns that may have other values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({1:[np.nan,'active','b'],2:['active','active','active'],3:[np.nan,np.nan,'active']})
```

Brings this:

```
        1       2       3
0     NaN  active     NaN
1  active  active     NaN
2       b  active  active
```

Then you sum rowwise with a condition:

```
np.sum(df1=='active', axis=1) #axis=1 tells it to do rowwise operation instead of columnwise.
```

Output:

```
0    1
1    2
2    2
```

Comment: thank you so much Juan!